# Python function not returning value using Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying to create a python function and return a value (using google app engine).  The function is being called and the value is being assigned to a variable with no problem, but when I try to use the variable I get a "local variable 'converted_day' referenced before assignment" error.

I am a noobie ...I know this should be simple. -Thanks for any advise you can give.

**Here are snippets of the Python code:**

```
class ViewMentorProfileHandler(BaseHandler2):
    def OneDayBackwards(self, mentor_day_display):
        if mentor_day_display == "MO":
            converted_day = "SU"    
        if mentor_day_display == "SU":
            converted_day = "SA"    
        if mentor_day_display == "SA":
            converted_day = "FR"
        if mentor_day_display == "FR":
            converted_day = "TH"
        if mentor_day_display == "TH":
            converted_day = "WE"
        if mentor_day_display == "WE":
            converted_day = "TU"
        if mentor_day_display == "TU":
            converted_day = "MO"
        logging.info('*OneDayBackwards function fired -- converted_day = %s*' % converted_day) 
        return converted_day

    def post(self, **kwargs):
        if (AM_PM == "PM") and (converted_AM_PM == "AM"):  
            self.OneDayBackwards(mentor_day_display);

        logging.info('***********converted_day = %s**********' % converted_day)   # getting error from this line of code.
```

Comment: Is it possible mentor_day_display is None? Try and add a default value incase none of those IF statements are True... at the worst, you'd be following good practice.

Comment: No, it should be there.  I am getting this in the log to show that the function working fine... just not getting the variable back to where I can use it.               "INFO     2013-09-18 19:11:47,091 handlers.py:676] *OneDayBackwards function fired -- converted_day = SA*"

Comment: I tried adding the default like you suggested, but no luck-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually declare `converted_day` anywhere within your `post` method.
You also use the `self.OneDayBackwards` method without assigning the return value to a variable, which I suspect is what you intended to do.

Modifying the `post` method to look like the below should resolve the issue:

```
def post(self, **kwargs):
    if (AM_PM == "PM") and (converted_AM_PM == "AM"):  
        converted_day = self.OneDayBackwards(mentor_day_display)
    else:
        converted_day = "SOME DEFAULT HERE"

    logging.info('***********converted_day = %s**********' % converted_day)
```

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks Michael0x2a - I changed by post to yours and that fixed the error, what do you mean when you say, "You also use the self.OneDayBackwards method without assigning the return value to a variable"?   Is that the "converted_day = self.OneDayBackwards(mentor_day_display)" part?  --Thanks again

Comment: @MattEllis -- sorry, that was confusingly worded. I meant that you originally did just `self.OneDayBackwards(mentor_day_display)`. The method returns a value, but you never used it. The new version *does* store and remember the value in the `converted_day` variable. (Remember, due to scope, the `converted_day` variable inside the `OneDayBackwards` method will not automatically be available outside it)